# Why is it that whenever there a is rendered attribute in a4j:commandLink the action attribute is not invoked?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, seam

I have a problem on a4j:commandLink, i conditionally rendering my link using rendered
attribute but unfortunately the action method is not invoke?

I made some findings and found out that there are problems in action attribute when conditionally rendering using just request scope bean.
The solution is to make the bean sessions scope.
I made my bean into session scope but still out of luck.

```
<a4j:commandLink rendered="#{someBean.enable}" action="#{someBean.doThis}" />
```

Here is my bean:

```
@Name("someBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.Session)
public class SomeBean{

private boolean enable;

    public void doThis(){
        //not called here
    }

    //getters setters
}
```

Am i missing something?

I am using jsf2, richfaces and seam.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: post the code to demonstrate the problem plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the version of richfaces or seam you're using but seems it is version 3.3 for richfaces
if so, use ajaxSingle="true" attribute.

Comment: great its working but how did it happen. and why putting ajaxsingle=true solve this. im confuse. :)

Comment: ajaxSingle attribute is supposed to orders to include only a value of the current component, but as you can see it is the only way all components in form are posted , for more info see this JBoss community thread: http://community.jboss.org/thread/158665?tstart=0

Comment: i get the same error for h:selectOneMenu using a4j:support but when i put ajaxsingle="true" the method isn't firing again..waaaaa

Comment: it has disabled attribute to true; please help..why is this happening?